# Direflow build "fails"

Tags: webpack, stenciljs

After including a npm package with some webcomponents built by stenciljs my direflow build failed with

```
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename vendor.js
```

I **fixed** this error by modifying the `direflow-webpack.js`

```js
const { webpackConfig } = require('direflow-scripts');
module.exports = (config, env) => ({
    ...webpackConfig(config, env),
    output: {
        ...webpackConfig(config, env).output,
        chunkFilename: "[name].js", // this fixed the chunks issue. Default in direflow is vendor.js
    }
})
```

Now running `direflow-scripts build` correctly creates a `direflowBundle.js` file in which everything seems in order.

But the build "fails" when trying to report filesizes

```
...

Filesizes after gzip:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ******\demo-direflow\build\3.js

....
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

PS: I really want to tag this question with the `direflow` tag but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `direflow-webpack.js` as below solved it.

```
const { webpackConfig } = require('direflow-scripts');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = (config, env) => {
  const wc = webpackConfig(config, env);
  wc.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({maxChunks: 1}))
  return wc
}
```